# How to call a function from a directive from an outside controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

it seems that there are some questions online with similar matters but no solution worked for me.

I'm having a directive, let's say that includes a function like this (within the directive):

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

     scope.myfunction = function (){
          console.log('function run');
     };
}
```

Witch i want to make it run (call it) from a controller with something simple like this:

```
$scope.myFunction();
```

So i can call it from a part of my page outside the directive code let's say like this:

```
<button ng-click="myFunction()">Run</button>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You could share the scope instance rather than creating a new one as I assume you are doing, or you could move the function into a service and inject that both in the directive and your controller?
There is probably a better way to design this but it is hard to tell without any context of why you are trying to do this

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21202670/5052704

See if this helps.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14883476/1099240

Comment: No both answers doesn't work for me. Well second one is a different approach that it's not good for what i'm doing.

Comment: do you wanted to call the directive method from outer controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i got the solution by broadcasting scope like this.

In controller:

```
$scope.startFunction = function(){
    $scope.$broadcast('startfunction');
};
```

In directive:

```
scope.$on('startfunction', function () {
     console.log('function run');
});
```

Comment: If view is already loaded then brodcast wont get called for second time. any suggestion?